# Hardcode/Set the First URL suggestion for a domain in Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

What I want to achieve is that when I write "super" in the Firefox URL bar, it should suggest **superuser.com/questions** instead of **superuser.com** as the first suggestion, irrespective of my usage patterns. It may resort to its own algorithm to rank URL suggestions after the first hardcoded suggestion.

And I would like to do that sort of configuration for multiple domains.

I have set `broswer.urlbar.autoFill` to `true`. So if I could get the above working, visiting a preferred URL under a domain would become much more efficient.

Does there exist a firefox addon which provides such functionality?

UPDATE:

According to @timbooo's suggestion, on bookmarking the URL, it comes up as the first suggestion, but when I bookmark the URL, it doesn't come up as the first suggestion.

So what `places.frecency.*` parameters need to be tweaked to ensure that a bookmarked URL has a very high priority?

UPDATE:

If I type "superuse" it shows "superuser.com/questions" but if its even a letter less, like "superus" it shows "superuser.com"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>I don't know of any add-on that provides this (yet), but when you're having a bookmark for `superuser.com/questions` it should always suggest the bookmark first.</s>

[image]

**UPDATE**

The [frecency algorith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_Places_frecency_algorithm) determines how the results are ordered in the dropdown menu.

> Firefox 3 introduced a number of
>   improvements to the Location Bar.
>   Among them were changes to how sites
>   are ordered in the dropdown menu.
>   Firefox takes into account how
>   frequently and how recently sites in
>   the browser history were visited,
>   combining them into a statistic called
>   “frecency.” The frecency of sites is
>   calculated when the browser is idle.
>   The way frecency is computed can be
>   tweaked by a number of preferences.

Reference: [Places.frecency.(visit type)VisitBonus](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Places.frecency.%28visit_type%29VisitBonus)

Comment: @timboo, doesn't work for me. I just bookmarked it and tries accessing, still shows the root domain as a suggestion. Restart Firefox, still just the root domain. And I don't have any other bookmarks for the superuser website.

Comment: may be one of the `places.frequency.*` parameters need to be tweaked

Comment: As a workaroung you could push your `places.frecency.bookmarkVisitBonus` and decrease the `places.frecenc.typedVisitBonus`. This way the visited bookmarks are more important than any other visited sites. More information here: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Places.frecency.(visit_type)VisitBonus and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_Places_frecency_algorithm

Comment: i changed bookmarkvisitbonus to 10000 and typevisitbonus to 1000, but doesn't help

Comment: Maybe you have to give it some time or visit the bookmark more often. I don't know how Firefox calculates the ranking exactly.

Comment: Finally it did come up to the top of urlbar search results!